Curl command in the YAML Pipeline for Azure DevOps
I am trying to call the api using curl command in the Azure DevOps Pipeline and getting the below Error

/azp/_work/_temp/xxxxxx-xx-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.sh: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/azp/_work/_temp/xxxxxx-xx-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.sh: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file
##[error]Bash exited with code '2'.

Here is the step i am trying to call the CURL Command
steps:
- script: |
  echo "Sending POST Request...""
  curl -X POST "URL" \\ 
  \-H "Content-Type:  application/json" \
  \-H "Authorization: Bearer PATTOKEN"
  displayName: 'Send POST request using CURL'

I need to call the api from the Azure DevOps Pipeline. Please help me in resolving the issue

Did the answer below help?

Your YAML string is not properly indented and your command doesn't seem well formed.
Try the following:
 - script: |
     echo "Sending POST Request..."
     curl -X POST "URL" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer PATTOKEN"
   displayName: 'Send POST request using CURL'

Also, consider using the folded style (indicated by a right angle bracket >) instead of  the literal style (indicated by a pipe |) to make your code cleaner and get rid of the backslash \:
 - script: >
     echo "Sending POST Request..."

     curl -X POST "URL"
     -H "Content-Type: application/json"
     -H "Authorization: Bearer PATTOKEN"
   displayName: 'Send POST request using CURL'

Please note that line breaks are treated differently depending on if you use the folded or literal style. See YAML multiline strings and How do I break a string in YAML over multiple lines? for more details.
